# Inverse of completely multiplicative function with respect to dirichlet convolution

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function, dirichlet-convolution

Is the inverse of a completely multiplicative function $f(n)$ with respect to Dirichlet convolution again completely multiplicative? I know that for multiplicative functions its true(Apostol's Analytic number theory page 36) but I think it doesn't hold for completely multiplicative functions. So i was looking for a counterexample(if it isn't true)...

Comment: They are again multiplicative, but not necessarily completely multiplicative.

Comment: I anticipated that. I was looking for a counterexample for a completely multiplicative function whose inverse isn't completely multiplicative.

Comment: Your first sentence can be misunderstood then. Anyway, take the constant $1$ function. Its inverse is the möbius function.

Comment: The inverse of $f(n)$ is $\mu(n)f(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirichlet inverse of the completely multiplicative constant $1$ function, i.e. $f(n) = 1$ for all $n$ is given by the Möbius function $\mu$ which is only multiplicative but not completely multiplicative.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. In general $f^{-1}=\mu f$.